# how to assign self.attributes in a class in a for loop?

Tags: python, class, for-loop

I have a class in which I read a json into a dictionary and I want to assign in a loop self.variable based on the key-value pairs in the dictionary as in:

```
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, name):
        tables_metadata = json.loads(jsonfilepath)

        self.name = name
        for key, value in tables_metadata.items:
            self.key = value
```

How can I pass the key value of the dictionary as the self.name_of_the_variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [setattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr):

```
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, name):
        tables_metadata = json.loads(jsonfilepath)

        self.name = name
        for key, value in tables_metadata.items:
            setattr(self, key, value)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setattr(self, key, value)`.

However, I don't know your use case, but in most cases it's probably better to just store the actual dict as attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can update `self.__dict__`:

```
self.__dict__.update(tables_metadata)
```